# android http request doesn't work on device, in emulator works

Tags: android, request

I know there was an other post like this but it doesn't help.

My Code is working in an emulator but on the device I get an Exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null

Permissions are set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And here is the code:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class mainAct extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        ARequestTask task = new ARequestTask();

        task.execute(new String[] {});

    }

    class ARequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String hallo = "test";
            Log.d("EMAIL", hallo);

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI uri = new URI("http://.../android/index.php");
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);

                HttpResponse responseGET = client.execute(get);
                HttpEntity resEntity = responseGET.getEntity();

                if (resEntity != null) {
                    Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // use the result as you wish
        }
    }

}
```

Every time the HttpGet will be executed the Exception comes up BUT only on the device .

Comment: Seeing how the error complains about your host name, you might not want to obfuscate the host name in your example code. Or is your host name intended to be "..."?

Comment: Also, just try putting the host-name String directly into your HttpGet constructor. `HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://.../android/index.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
URI uri = URI.parse("http://.../android/index.php");
```

After you do that look in the uri object in the debugger. check if it is valid.
Good luck.